# Convert TZ datetime to timestamp

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I have column of dates in the format below in a pandas dataframe.

What is the most effective way to convert

2021-11-06T21:54:35.825Z

to

2021-11-6 21:54:35

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') only returns 2021-11-06 without the timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.dt` accessor on Pandas Series followed by by `.strftime` property [dt.strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html), to format datetime into desired string representation.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ["2021-11-06T21:54:35.825Z"]})
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime(fmt)
```

returns

```
0    2021-11-06 21:54:35
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Or if you don't want to have zero padding before the day, you can use: `fmt="%Y-%m-%-d %H:%M:%S"` (notice the hyphen between `%` and `d`). This results in: `2021-11-6 21:54:35`

Comment: Thank you so much